# Is creating a two row button layout on the ribbon possible using xml?

Tags: xml, vba, user-interface, powerpoint, ribbon

I'm trying to create a custom button group on a new ribbon group in PowerPoint.

While adding all the relevant commands to the new group works without problems I am struggling to arrange them in the way I would like to

Below I attached the xml code I am currently using for the example shown below

```
<group 
    id="Group_Font_Formatting"
    label="Font Formatting">

        <box id="box_Font_Formatting_test">
        <buttonGroup id="buttonGroup_Font_Formatting1">
                    <toggleButton idMso="Bold" />
                    <toggleButton idMso="Italic" />
                    <toggleButton idMso="Underline" />
        </buttonGroup>

        <buttonGroup id="buttonGroup_Font_FormattingTest">
                    <gallery idMso="FontColorPicker" />
        </buttonGroup>

        <buttonGroup id="buttonGroup_Font_Formatting2">
                    <toggleButton 
                        id="Superscript" 
                        imageMso="Superscript"
                        onAction="Superscript" />

                    <toggleButton 
                        id="Subscript" 
                        imageMso="Subscript"
                        onAction="Subscript" />
        </buttonGroup>
        </box>

        <box id="box_Font_Formatting">
                    <comboBox idMso="Font" />
                    <comboBox idMso="FontSize" />
        </box>

</group >
```

Which gives me this (two rows, but not arranged in the middle of the group)

[image: Three row layout]

However, I am trying to get a layout that looks like one of the default groups (two rows arranged in the middle of the group)

[image: Two row layout]

I've been searching around the msdn documentation pages but wasn't able to find what I am looking for. Also browsing through related topics on here did not provide me with the information to proceed on my own.

So, my question: Is my idea achievable using xml?

- If so a code snippet or at least a helpful link would be highly appreciated
- If it's not possible, then what would you suggest to get closer to the two rows layout?

Comment: There isn't any attribute to equally space the items. It is a limitation of the ribbon xml.

Comment: @Shyam Ok, so there exisits no workaround to format a group similar to the outline shown in picture two?

Comment: Not to my knowledge